# Find all cycles in a dictionary containing more than 1 cycle

Tags: python, dictionary, nodes, cycle, directed-graph

Given the following dictionary of cycles:

```
{'E': ['F'], 'F': ['C', 'G'], 'C': ['E'], 'G': ['H'], 'H': ['I'], 'I': ['J', 'D'], 'J': ['D'], 'D': ['E']}
```

where the keys represent the parent node and the value is all of its child nodes that it points to (this is representing a directed graph).

It can be seen that there are 3 cycles:

1. E -> F -> C
2. E -> F -> G -> H -> I -> J -> D
3. E -> F -> G -> H -> I -> D

I'm trying to figure out a method or function that would be able to extract all of the cycles so I could output or return the three cycles :

> EFC

> EFGHIJD

> EFGHID

I'm looking for a solution in Python please! Thanks :)

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried. This is not a homework forum for you to post a question and someone will give you the answer.

Comment: I tried doing for loops to iterate over the dictionary and print the key or values of the keys out but I really have no idea how to group them together as cycles.

Answer (score 1):

One way the get all the cycles for one starting node would be:

```
def cycles(graph, start):
    results = []
    paths = [(start,)]
    while paths:
        path = paths.pop()
        childs = set(graph.get(path[-1], []))
        if start in childs:
            results.append(path)
        paths.extend(
                  (path + (child,))
                  for child in childs.difference(path)
              )
    return results
```

With your graph and starting node `E` you will get (`print(cycles(g, 'E'))` with `g` your dictionary):

```
[('E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'D'),
 ('E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'D'),
 ('E', 'F', 'C')]
```

If you want all the cycles in a graph you'll have to do some more work: One single starting node usually doesn't lead to all cycles of a graph. One way to achieve that would be to iterate over all nodes, apply `cycles`, and then collect all the results:

```
result = [cycle for node in g for cycle in cycles(g, node)]
```

```
[('E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'D'),
 ('E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'D'),
 ('E', 'F', 'C'),
 ('F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'D', 'E'),
 ('F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'D', 'E'),
 ('F', 'C', 'E'),
 ('C', 'E', 'F'),
 ('G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'D', 'E', 'F'),
 ('G', 'H', 'I', 'D', 'E', 'F'),
 ('H', 'I', 'J', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'),
 ('H', 'I', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'),
 ('I', 'J', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'),
 ('I', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'),
 ('J', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'),
 ('D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'),
 ('D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J')]
```

But this way will lead to some redundancy: `('E', 'F', 'C')`, `('C', 'E', 'F')`, and `( 'F', 'C', 'E')` are essentially the same (etc.). If you want to get rid of that you could do something like this:

```
results = []
d = {node: set(g.get(node, [])) for node in g}
nodes = list(d)
while nodes:
    node = nodes.pop()
    results.extend(cycles(d, node))
    del d[node]
    for other_node in d:
        d[other_node].discard(node)
```

`print(results)`:

```
[('D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'),
 ('D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'),
 ('C', 'E', 'F')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
d = {'E': ['F'], 'F': ['C', 'G'], 'C': ['E'], 'G': ['H'], 'H': ['I'], 'I': ['J', 'D'], 'J': ['D'], 'D': ['E']}
def get_cycles(n, o = None, c = []):
   if n == o: #check if current node being examined is the same as the start
      yield c #if the condition is met, then a cycle is found and the path is yielded back
   else:
      #get the children of the current node from d and iterate over only those that have not been encountered before (except if the node is the same as the start)
      for i in filter(lambda x:x not in c or x == o, d.get(n, [])):
         #recursively find the children of this new node `i`, saving the running path (c + [n])
         yield from get_cycles(i, o = n if o is None else o, c = c + [n])

print(list(get_cycles('E')))
print(list(get_cycles('D')))
```

Output:

```
[['E', 'F', 'C'], ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'D']]
[['D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'], ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']]
```

Comment: wow great solution thank you! Do you mind explaining? I'm having difficulties understanding. If you know a way to write this a more simple/easier to read please share as well! thanks

Comment: @Yasmine Glad to help! Please see the comments in my edit and do let me know if you have any other questions.